# Is there any way to track device location even when the app is in its killed state?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, background, geolocation

Is there any way to track device location in which our app is installed even when the app is on its killed state in flutter ? Just like some device tracker. Any packages ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to check out this package.
[background_locator](https://pub.dev/packages/background_locator).
It works great in background but you might consider optimising it because continuously tracking device location might cause battery issues.